# Programmatically creating event handlers in C#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a combobox with OwnerDrawMode implemented as follows:

```
this.comboBox8.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
this.comboBox8.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(comboBox8_DrawItem);
this.comboBox8.MeasureItem += new    MeasureItemEventHandler(comboBox8_MeasureItem);
```

That works fine, but I now want to create another five similar comboboxes (9 to 13) which will be essentially identical e.g the MeasureItems are just

```
private void comboBox8_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemWidth = 44;
    e.ItemHeight = 15;
}

private void comboBox9_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemWidth = 44;
    e.ItemHeight = 15;
}
```

etc.

It seems simple but very kludgy to just retype them :-)

When I come to the Draw Items they contain code snippet that don't change from box to box (as in the above, but also code snippets where the logic doesn't change but the names change from  8 to 9-13

```
private void comboBox8_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox8.DataSource = c8_suits;

        if (e.Index >= 0) e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox8.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
              e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    }
```

TIA.

Comment: So just have one then and use the same one... it's not like you have different logic to worry about. Not really sure what your question is to be honest

Comment: Also... assuming you kept them all, why would you *re-type*? Have you not heard of copy and paste?

Comment: @Shreevadhan's answer is most likely what you're looking for. But one thing to consider - is *all* of the logic the same for each button click?

Comment: The logic is the same but the naming changes and I'm not sure how to implement that.  For example, when I come to the Draw events there will be lines like if (e.Index >= 0) e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox8.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                  e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault); with 8 replaced by 9 and so on.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you could use the `sender` and cast it to a `ComboBox` to get its `Items` in the logic. Could you perhaps include this logic in your question, so it's a bit clearer, please? It proves quite vital to the question.

Comment: @Geoff.  Thanks for that                                                                          private void comboBox8_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
        // Code snippet that doesn't change from box to box
        
        // Code snippet that changes only by change of name 8, 9 ... 13
        
            comboBox8.DataSource = c8_suits;
            
            if (e.Index >= 0) e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox8.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                  e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }

Comment: @DLyons - could you add that into your original question, rather than as a comment? It's becomes really hard to read in comments and like I said, can prove a vital part of the question :)

Comment: @DLyons: With your comments, I believe this now becomes a duplicate question. [like this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217205/get-access-to-the-sender-control-c-sharp) though I would have thought there are better duplicate questions, I just can't seem to find them right now

Comment: @Musefan Thanks - will look at that now.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void comboBox_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemWidth = 44;
    e.ItemHeight = 15;
}

. . .

this.comboBox1.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(comboBox_MeasureItem);
this.comboBox2.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(comboBox_MeasureItem);
. . .
```

Comment: OP says "Programatically generating event handlers"... how does this generate event handlers?

Comment: @musefan I answered the question based on the description because I found the title irrelevant.

Comment: yeah... but the title is the only thing that half resembles a question. I know it's probably what the OP should do, but I just feel it's a non-question, which would imply it shouldn't have an answer

Comment: @Shreevardhan See comment above.  Some pieces of code don't change and your answer is perfect for those.  But there are snippets where the logic doesn't change but the names do and it's those that I'd like to generate rather than "re-type"

Comment: @Musefan  It's easy, but not helpful, to criticise.

Comment: @DLyons: That depends on the person being criticised... I find criticism to be pretty helpful most of the time

Comment: @Musefan  Come back in 20 years and let me know how it's worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of thing:

```
for (var i = 9; i <= 13; i++)
{
    var cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.MeasureItem += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.ItemWidth = 44;
        e.ItemHeight = 15;
    };
}
```