# Winform copy button text to textbox using universal method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

So this is a fairly straightforward thing, and I am just curious if there is a better way to do it to save lines of code.  For class we are making a teletype machine.  Basically there is a textbox, and a series of buttons A-Z and 0-9.  When you click the button it adds the corresponding letter/number to the textbox.  When you click send, it adds the contents of the textbox to a label and resets the textbox.  Everything works and it only took a few minutes to build.  However there is a mess of redundant lines and I was curious if there is a way to clean up the code with a method.

This is my current code.

```
private void btn_A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        box_UserInput.Text = box_UserInput.Text + "A";
    }
```

As you can see, it is very simplistic and straight forward.  Click A, and "A" gets added to the textbox.  However the Text property of the button is also just "A" and I want to know if there is a way to just copy the text property of that button and add it to the textbox string.

Something like this, except with a universal approach where instead of having to specify btn_A it just inherits which button to copy based on the button clicked.  That way I can use the same line of code on every button.

```
    private void btn_A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        box_UserInput.Text = box_UserInput.Text + btn_A.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get access to the Sender control - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217205/get-access-to-the-sender-control-c-sharp)

Comment: Try to stick to $"{box_UserInput.Text}{btn_A.Text}" because using '+' in C# is bad practice.  (From Microsoft training material after a C# version upgrade.)

Comment: Use a sender cast.  ((Button)sender).Text - something like that...

Comment: @Martheen that is an interesting way to do it.  For an extreme idea what about rendering an image in Blender and creating defined regions in a JSON file import both and use the current mouse location, checking bounds of the JSON imported regions then adding that to the output control.  I almost want to make that just for fun!

Comment: @James like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286617/creating-clickable-c-sharp-image-map-in-winforms I suppose

Comment: @Marteen Yes, that kind of thing. :)

Comment: @Marteen I worked on touch screen products before mobile phones had them.  Including a TI embedded controller project using a monochrome LCD touchscreen for a heating system.  But that was using C and interfacing with hardware directly.  It was fun because I set up a project to simulate the user interface on the PC too.  This was to build on the UI and UX in a more convenient way.

Comment: @Martheen that doesn't really help, I'm using actual buttons not points on an image.  Thank you though

Comment: @KyleC My first link literally point out the same method as the accepted answer, casting sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this which is more universal as the Control class contains the Text property.  Also, using the best practice $"".

```
private void btn_A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    box_UserInput.Text = $"{box_UserInput.Text}{((Control)sender).Text}";
}
```

You can also assign the same event to each button.  Create an event, say addControlTextOnClick and assign the same event to each button.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addControlTextOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        box_UserInput.Text = $"{box_UserInput.Text}{((Control)sender).Text}";
    }
}
```

You can even shorten this more using this C# construct:

```
private void addControlTextOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    box_UserInput.Text = $"{box_UserInput.Text}{((Control)sender).Text}";
```

[image]

Comment: This is hands down the best answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for, and the explanation helped me learn a new thing about how the event handler works for future assignments.  You rock man!